# composeTestRule checking that atleast 1 item exists

Tags: kotlin, junit, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack-compose-testing

I have a list which has 2 different items. However, if the user gets close to the end of the list then the 2 same items are added again and again to create an infinite scrolling feel.

I've created a test to basically verify that the item exists like so:

```
composeTestRule
  .onAllNodesWithContentDescription("Home")
  .assertCountEquals(2)
```

As you can see this just finds nodes with the content description of "Home" and checks if their are 2.

Currently, this works as the screen size is small but let's say the screen size is doubled then this will fail as the `assertCountEquals(2)` would need to check for `4`.

I was wondering to make this code better, is there a way to basically check that atleast 1 exists?

Answer (score 2):

onAllNodes methods return an array, grab the first element and check whether it exists or is displayed.

```
composeTestRule
  .onAllNodesWithContentDescription("Home")
  .onFirst().assertExists()
```